# My footer won't go to the bottom of the page

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, jhtml

Hello can anyone help me and let me know as to why my footer won't stay at the bottom of the page. I have my logo at the top followed by navigation and then a custom HTML module full of text. Instead of it being at the bottom it stays in the middle of the page.

Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have too much code to post here so if you would like access to the website administration panel you are more than welcome too.

http://www.webbmaster.com.au/web-programs/questdesign/index.php/terms-and-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with a very simple fix. In your template index.php file, you will see the following:

```
<div class="body">
```

which you need to replace with

```
<div class="body clearfix">
```

For more information on a `clearfix`, please have a read of the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix

Hope this helps